# How can I find how many times does 101b show in the number?

Tags: assembly, x86, binary, bit-manipulation

I need to find out how many times does the sequence 101b shows in a 16 bit number. But I need to find also the ones that are far away.

For example: in the number 01010101 it appears 4 times. Because 3 are part of it and the fourth one (if index 0 is the left bit) is composed of the 3 bits at index 1, 4, and 7.

Because you can relate to it as symmetrical 101b sequence.

It seems really complicated, but does it really? I think it might just be a little tricky.

I managed to find out how many times it shows regularly, like the 3 that you can see in the example number. But I don't know how can I find the symmetrical ones.
EDIT:My teacher did mean rotation and I misunderstood the problem, thanks for everyone for the help though

```
    mov cx,15
Check:

    push dx;the number that I need to check
    and dx,0111b
    cmp dx,101b
    jne Again
Again:

    pop dx
    shr dx,1
    loop check
```

Comment: We normally number bits starting at the LSB = bit 0.  Only PowerPC and S/390 counts bits from the left, and most people consider that weird (http://alanclements.org/power%20pc.html).

Comment: You only listed 3 positions.  Which one is the 4th `101b`?  Also, one of your positions (index 4 counting from the left) is a `0`, so it's not the start or end of a `101b`.  Are you counting wrap-around from the top bit, so there's a `101b` starting at bit 7, and including bit 0 and 1?  If so, then sivizius answer is what you want, but with 8-bit rotate.  As a 16-bit number, you have `0000000001010101b`.

Comment: I didn't get it. If 1,4,7 is a match (ie non contiguous bits can match), why not say 3,4,7?

Comment: @BeeOnRope: I think because the gaps need to be symmetric.  So `1.0.1` is a pattern we're looking for, but not `10.1`.  This question keeps getting more and more confusing as the OP keeps adding new stuff in comments.  e.g. even length patterns like `1001b` [are now part of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56608545/how-can-i-find-how-many-times-does-101b-show-in-the-number/56611445?noredirect=1#comment99798739_56611445), but we don't know how that's allowed to scale up with gaps.

Comment: @PeterCordes - indeed, it is really confusing. The gaps need to be symmetric in size or also in content?

Comment: @PeterCordes As it looks,I probably did not understand the question right and my teacher probably meant rotation.She  had wrote something about that but I misunderstood it.I asked her about it and im waiting for a reply now.about the 1001b, I thought it is a part of it because I thought the pattern is both symmetrical and any amount of 0's match.Forgot to mention it.anyways I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

somthing like this (not tested):

```
mov dx, yourNumber
mov cx, 16
xor ax, ax
count:
  mov bx, dx
  and bx, 0b111
  cmp bx, 0b101
  jne nope
     inc ax
  nope:
  rol dx, 1
  dec cx
  jnz count
```

so basically, you rotate the register 16 times and on each iteration to test, if the lowest 3 bits by masking the register with 0b111 are equal to 0b101. after this calculation, the result is in `ax` and the number you tested should be still in `dx`

Comment: can you explain what is 0b111? I never used it and this syntax is not familiar for me.

Comment: 0b111 = 111b = 7 = 0x07 = 07h = 07 = $07 = … depending on the actual assembler.

Comment: It gives the same result as my solution.And now when I look at it,its the same as mine...  Did you read the problem?

Comment: @TheNiv: The example in your question only has a 4th `101b` at the wraparound if it's an 8-bit number, not 16.  Use `rol dl, 1` instead of `rol dx, 1` if you want to check 8-bit numbers.  (And of course reduce the loop counter).

Comment: @PeterCordes I need to check 16 bit number,but isn't my solution the same as sivizius one? with shift instead of rol

Comment: @TheNiv: no, this solution also checks for the extra `101b` that wraps around from the top to bottom.  That's *why* this uses a rotate.  The other changes (like `mov` to a tmp register instead of push/pop) are just optimizations, and yes it is otherwise the same.  If you need to check 16-bit numbers, then how does `0000000001010101b` contain 4 instances? 3 is the right answer as far as I can see.  Please update your question to clarify what you want.

Comment: @PeterCordes I didn't understand how does it checks also for the 101b that wraps around from the top to button. Can you explain why?

Comment: @PeterCordes 01010101 was an example for a number that has  a symmetrical 101b sequence. as I said in the question,it has 4 instances because 3 are part of it and the fourth one is (if index 0 is the left bit)-index 1, 4, and 7. It should work the same for both 8 bit and 16 bit numbers because only the the size of the number is different.

Answer (score 3):

**The logic:**

If you XOR the value with 1010101010101010b (0xAA), any 4-bit group that was 0101b will become 1111b, and any group that wasn't won't.

If you add 1 to 1111b it will overflow, and if you add 1 to any other number it won't overflow. You can arrange this so when the addition overflows it causes the carry flag to be set.

You can use the `adc` instruction to add the carry flag to a count/sum to get the total number of groups that overflowed (the number of groups that were 0101b originally).

This will only find 0101b that is aligned to the start of the group. To make it work for "0101b anywhere" you'd need to do it 4 times, with a rotate between each time.

**The code:**

```
    mov cx,4           ;Number of times to rotate/repeat
    xor ax,ax          ;ax = current sum of 4-bit groups that were 0101b = 0

.nextRotation:
    mov bx,dx          ;bx = the value
    xor bx,0xAAAA      ;dx = any 4-bit group that was 0101b is now 1111b
    add bx,0x1000      ;Carry set if fourth/highest group was originally 0101
    adc ax,0           ;Add carry to the sum
    add bl,0x10        ;Carry set if second group was originally 0101b
    adc ax,0           ;Add carry to the sum
    shl bx,4
    add bx,0x1000      ;Carry set if third group was originally 0101b
    adc ax,0           ;Add carry to the sum
    add bl,0x10        ;Carry set if first/lowest group of 4 bits was originally 0101b
    adc ax,0           ;Add carry to the sum
                       ;ax = number of 4-bit groups that were originally 0101b

    rol dx,1
    loop .nextRotation
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain what does it means to add the carry flag to a number?I never heard of this instruction.And what does the x means in your assembler? I mean what is 0x1000? is it 1000b?

Comment: @TheNiv: look it up in the manual: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ADC.html.  The "standard" use-case is for adding integers that are wider than a register, but you can use it for "tricks", too.

Comment: Mostly; `adc ax,0` does `ax = ax + 0 + carry`, which is equivalent to `ax = ax + carry`.

Comment: @TheNiv: `0x1000` means hex, same as in C or many many other languages.  So it's `1000h` in a DOS assembler that doesn't support `0x` syntax.  Is x86 assembly your first programming language?

Comment: @PeterCordes No, my first programming language was basic C,but very basic.Then I started learning C# before I started to also learn it in school. And this year I started learning in school assembly and C#,both on low level because its the first year but assembly was new for me.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Ah - I think you're right. Give me a few minutes :-)

Comment: Turns out sivizious and I were wrong, it's not rotation, it's with don't-care bits in between like `1?0?1`.  I clarified the question slightly, and posted an answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes: D'oh. In that case my approach can't work.

Comment: Well it's great for finding the no-gap `101b` sequences so you don't have to check for them in a shift loop, just the `1.0.1b` and `1..0..1b` and so on.  Probably each one separately.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Now I'm thinking; if you scan the bits and detect a transition from `0` to `1` or from `1` to `0` (like, detecting rising/falling edges) but cheat (`x = x ^ (x << 1)`) to do that fast; then count the number of transitions, then use "number of transitions" to determine the result somehow (not sure how yet but I'm imagining some kind of "pyramid relationship").

Comment: .. maybe something vaguely like "`occurrences = transitions/2 + transitions/4 + transitions/8`.

Comment: Well, my thoughts are wrong so ignore my "count transitions" idea.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I've understood where the 4th copy is.  I (and @sivizius) were thinking it was composed of bits 7, 0, and 1 (wrapping around to the top bit).  But apparently that's not what you want.

(Also your bit numbering makes no sense.  You say the top bit of your 8-bit number is bit 0, but in comments you insist you want to work with 16-bit numbers.  So what bit-number is `1<<15`?)

Anyway, I think you want to find patterns like `1.0.1` and `1..0..1`?  (Where `.` is a don't-care placeholder in the pattern that can match either a 0 or 1).

You can look for those with something like this (inside a `shr dx, 1` loop).

```
; dumb brute force method.
countloop:                   ; do {
    mov  ax, dx
    and  al, 111b               ; select the bits that matter in 101
    cmp  al, 101b               ; check that it's the pattern we want
    ; do count += ZF somehow

    mov  ax, dx
    and  al, 10101b             ; select the bits that matter in 1.0.1
    cmp  al, 10001b             ; check that it's the pattern we want
    ; do count += ZF somehow

    mov  ax, dx
    and  al, 1001001b           ; select the bits that matter in 1..0..1
    cmp  al, 1000001b           ; check that it's the pattern we want
    ; do count += ZF somehow

   ... for all the rest of the patterns.
   ; Wider patterns will need to use AX instead of AL

    shr  dx, 1
    cmp  dx, 101b
    jae  countloop           ; }while(x >= 0b101);

;;; exit the loop as soon as DX contains no bits high enough to possibly match
;;; with a big loop, this is worth the extra cmp
;;; instead of just using jnz on the  shr dx,1  result
```

**So exactly like you're doing for `101b` except you force the don't-care bits to zero.**

I haven't thought of anything better than checking separately for *every* possible pattern separately inside the loop body.

The "count += ZF" could be (386) `setz al` / `add cl, al`, or a simple `jnz` over `inc cx`.  (I think the max possible count is less than 255, so an 8-bit counter is fine.)

Note that I'm not using `cx` as a loop counter, instead ending the loop after shifting all the bits out of `dx`

Another way to do it branchlessly without SETCC would be

```
   mov   ax, dx
   and   al, 10101b
   xor   al, 10001b
   sub   al, 1            ; set CF only if AL==0
   adc   cx, 0            ; cx += (al == 0b10001)
```

Comment: I showed a code that relates to my solution for a 16-bit numbers and showed an example of an 8-bit number so thats probably why it made no sense for you.Thanks for the answer though,I will think about your suggestion soon,because I think @Brendan solution mixed with my solution with rol instead of shl(like in sivizius's solution) will work.

Comment: @TheNiv: I'd highly recommend numbering bits from the LSB, like x86 manuals do, and everyone does in high-level languages too.  Then you wouldn't have this problem; bit 0 is still the lowest bit whether it's part of an 8-bit or 16-bit number.

Comment: Right,that's how I will number it next time

Comment: I realized now that the code you wrote is for checking 8 bit numbers.So to use it on 16 bit numbers can I just use 10010011001001b or I need to change something? Im not sure. In addition, your code does not contains all of the possabilites because if the number (lets say 8 bit as your code) is 1001b it is a 101b pattern but it wont consider it a pattern.(because of only one cmp with the number 10000001b)

Comment: @TheNiv: `ax` is a 16-bit register.  This check only for the `1..0..1` pattern at the bottom of a 16-bit register.  You still need this inside a shift loop to check for it at other offsets, and to check for other possible patterns like `1...0...1`.

Comment: @TheNiv: How does `1001b` fit?  Do *both* middle numbers have to be zero, or do `1011b` and/or `110b` also match?  You never mentioned any even-length patterns in your question.  And it's not clear how that gets wider.  Maybe you can describe your patterns in terms of regexes, in your question.

Comment: So I need to shr ax,8 right? I think it is more clear to work with al,ah instead of ax though.

Comment: @TheNiv: No, if you shift by 8 (or just look at the high half), you'll miss the pattern at an offset of 1 or 2 bits.  e.g. in `00111011100b`  the `1..0..1` pattern appears 2 bits to the left.  (So you'd find it after two right shifts.)

Comment: Im really confused now actually.But yes 1001b fits.In the question I meant even length patterns when I wrote symmetrical.edit: 110b does not match and 1011b does match.

Comment: Right,so  it should be a loop that shifts ax to the left 1 time each loop right?

Comment: @TheNiv: No, shift to the *right* like you were already doing, but check for more patterns inside each loop body.  That's the brute-force way.

Comment: Oops,I did mean right but accidently wrote left probably.I meant shift to the right.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems really complicated, but does it really? I think it might just be a little tricky.

Yes, it is really complicated. Here's how far I've got:

Step 1: Do "run-length encoding", ignoring leading and trailing zeros. Examples (for 8-bit numbers):

```
01010101 = 1(1s), 1(0s), 1(1s), 1(0s), 1(1s), 1(0s), 1(1s)
11001011 = 2(1s), 2(0s), 1(1s), 1(0s), 2(1s)
11111101 = 6(1s), 1(0s), 1(1s)
```

Step 2: Find permutations of "run of ones, run of zeros, run of ones" and multiply each run's count. Examples (for 8-bit numbers):

```
01010101 = 1(1s), 1(0s), 1(1s), 1(0s), 1(1s), 1(0s), 1(1s)
         = 1     *1     *1
         + 1     *1                   *1
         + 1     *1                                 *1
         + 1                   *1     *1
         + 1                   *1                   *1
         + 1                                 *1     *1
         +               1     *1     *1
         +               1     *1                   *1
         +               1                   *1     *1
         = 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1 = 9

11001011 = 2(1s), 2(0s), 1(1s), 1(0s), 2(1s)
         = 2     *2     *1
         + 2     *2                   *2
         + 2                   *1     *2
         +               1     *1     *2
         = 4+8+4+2 = 18

11111101 = 6(1s), 1(0s), 1(1s)
         = 6     *1     *1
         = 6
```

At this point; it's easy to conclude that an efficient implementation would involve lists, and would probably be easier to implement if recursion is used (find permutations that involve the first run of ones in the list, then discard the first run of ones and the first run of zeros and recurse).

Comment: I translated a part of the instructions and she wrote that you need to check it "in a circular fashion" (google translate because I don't know how to translate it myself).Maybe she did mean rotation? I will ask her about it tommrow.

Comment: If it is rotation,sorry... I appreciate your help anyways.

Comment: @TheNiv: If your description is accurate, then whether it's too complex to be given to students depends on how long it's meant to take to find a solution and how much you're supposed to have learnt at the stage of the course. In my opinion it might be suitable for students at the end of an advanced course, if they're given at least 40 hours, and if their solutions are given a score based on how good the attempt was (and not just a "zero points if it doesn't work, full points if it does work" way).

Comment: @TheNiv: "in a circular fashion" sounds like rotation to me, wrapping around the end of the number.  Not this very flexible pattern-matching.