# Which 2 cases aren't solved with this code?

Tags: assembly, binary, masm, x86-16

The problem is to find how many times the seuquence `101b` appears in a 16 bit number including rotation.

Example: in the number `1001011001010110b` the sequence appears 4 times.
3 that you can see directly (including an overlapping pair that share a `1` bit) and one across the wrap-around from low to high.  Specifically bit indexes 1, 0, 15 (where bit 0 is the rightmost bit)

Hebrew version:(requested)

> nibble הוא מספר בגודל מילה המורכבת מארבעה Fournibble
>   של אבעה תווים שקולטים בסדר הבא:
>   מהתו הראשון קולטים לוקחים את 4 סיביות שמאליות.
>   מהתו השני שקולטים קולטים לוקחים את 4 סיביות ימניות.
>   מהתו השלישי שקולטים קולטים לוקחים את 4 סיביות שמאליות.
>   מהתו הרביעי שקולטים קולטים לוקחים את 4 סיביות ימניות.
>   .ארבעה תווים N צריך לקלוט 
>    .אחד FourNibbleמכל ארבעה תווים רצופים שקולטים מייצרים 
>     .fournibbles את המספרים שמייצרים שומרים במערך
>   עבור כל מספר שקלטנו צריך למצוא כמה פעמים הרצף 101נמצא במספר.
>   הערה: צריך לבדוק את הרצף בצורה מעגלית. במספר הבינארי 010000101 הרצף מופיע פעמיים.

In the example that is written with the Hebrew version, my teacher wrote that the sequence appears twice.

This code worked for me and I tested it with some numbers. I don't understand 
 for what cases it doesn't work.

```
DATASEG
N equ 3
address dw ?        ;a variable that stores address of a function
address2 dw ?       ;a variable that stores address of a function inside other function
msg1 db 'enter 4 characters'
input db 7*N dup (?)      ;The input of the user
FourNibbles dw N dup(0)   ;An array to store the FourNibbles
results db N dup(0)       ;An array to store the results
.
.
.
proc FindResults; A Function that pushes the FourNibble and the results index of this FourNibble to the BinaryCheck function
    pop[address]
    mov di,offset FourNibbles
    mov si,offset results
    mov dx,N
CheckThisFourNibble:
    call SaveRegisters
    push si
    push [di]
    call BinaryCheck
    call GetRegisters
    inc si
    add di,2
    loop CheckThisFourNibble
    push[address]
    ret
endp FindResults

proc BinaryCheck
   pop[address2]    ; the return address
   pop dx           ;The 16 bit input number
   pop bx           ;the result address.
   mov cx,16 
Check:   
   push dx
   and dx,0111b
   cmp dx,101b
   jne Again
   inc[byte ptr bx]
Again:
   pop dx
   rol dx,1
   loop Check
   push[address2]
   ret
endp BinaryCheck
```

Comment: The code looks correct. What two cases are you referring to in the title?

Comment: In your example you specify that `10101` counts as two matches, perhaps the test case does not allow using the same bits for multiple matches?

Comment: @MargaretBloom She didn't tell me what were they.I was supposed to think about all the cases while doing my project(this code is a part of it) and I thought this code should work for all of them so I have no idea what 2 cases my teacher meant by saying it doesn't work for them.She told me in a test about it,to change the solution so it will be without loop and it will solve it.But I had no idea from where to start or what to do because I didn't know what are these cases.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I will translate it . You need to find how many times the sequence 101b appears in the number.Note: you need to check the number in a circular fashion( the last 3 words were translated with google translate).I know for sure the example is right and it is rotation though,because I didn't understand the assignment,asked my teacher to explain it to me and that's what she explained to me.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Its in hebrew though.Should I post only the example she gave maybe?

Comment: @MichaelPetch Done. Only the last part of it refers to this problem though

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yeah.

Comment: @MichaelPetch The rest of the assignment is just about from what to create the 16 bit number and where to save the results(number of times it appears).Do you still want to see it?

Comment: @MichaelPetch Finished to copy it... I see where this is going though she was wrong by saying that this code doen't work for 2 cases.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Too sad this test was an important test,which is a part a grade that determines what am I going to learn next year.How should I tell her about it ? Just to tell her,I asked in StackOverFlow and they said this code is currect and you should check again? Asking about the cases won't be possible because I had already asked her after the test and she said she will tell me about it next year.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I will post the entire function now.She linked me to this function.The code I added is just about saving the address and then pushing it.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Why though?In the test she told me to change this function only. I forgot to mention she wrote that it will do the same thing just without loop and it will solve those cases.Do you know how to do it?

Comment: @MichaelPetch Edited.It will be too long to post all of the code-140 lines.. I saw that the counter is initialized to 0 when running the program.Everything worked as excepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the example that is written with the Hebrew version,my teacher wrote that the sequence appears twice.

The example is "010000101".

```
010000101
      ***  1st
**      *  2nd
```

But that only happens if you do the wrapping at an 8-bit boundary.  As a 16-bit number, it's `00000000 010000101` and you correctly find that it has only one `101`.

> I don't understand for what cases it doesn't work.

You didn't zero the counter at `[bx]` beforehand. That's certainly a case where it won't work correctly.  (It would be easier to return a counter value in a register, instead of having the caller pass a pointer.)

And what's with the `pop`'s? If this is a procedure the first `pop` will hold the return address.  The normal way to access stack args in 16-bit code is by making a frame pointer with BP.

```
    push    bp
    mov     bp, sp
    mov     dx, [bp+4] ; The 16 bit number
    mov     bx, [bp+6] ; The results address
    mov     cx, 16
    mov     [bx], ch   ; CH=0
Check:   
    mov     ax, dx
    and     ax, 111b
    cmp     ax, 101b
    sete    al
    add     [bx], al
    ror     dx, 1
    dec     cx
    jnz     Check
    pop     bp
    ret     4
```

Or if you need an 8086-compatible version of this (counting ZF=1 results from `cmp` without `sete`), see the answers on [How can I find how many times does 101b show in the number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56608545/how-can-i-find-how-many-times-does-101b-show-in-the-number)

---

Your number "1001011001010110":

```
1001011001010110
           ***   1st
         ***     2nd
   ***           3rd
*             ** 4th
```

**From the updated code in the question**:

> ```
> loop CheckThisFourNibble
> ```

The `CX` register is not initialized. You've used `DX` to iterate so write:

```
dec dx
jnz CheckThisFourNibble
```

> ```
> msg1 db 'enter 4 characters'
> ```

I'm surprised to see that *msg1* doesn't have some kind of terminator like 0 or "$".

Comment: I initialized  the array that its address is in bx with 0's.And now I had posted the whole function,this isn't the first pop.

Comment: Your use of sete may not be valid if the course is 8086. They may not have access to the 386 instruction set and `sete`. If I were teaching an 8086 course I wouldn't accept `sete` in an answer.

Comment: Although unorthodox (and not a way normal people get parameters from the stack), what they did is technically correct. They popped the return address into a global and then restored the return address at the end. Whether they intended to be a stack to be cleaned up by the callee is hard to tell, but agreed that's what their code does.

Comment: @Sep Roland I had a lucky one right there with cx.Forgot to change dx to cx.But luckily,when I ran the program cx is 3 (N is also 3)when I call this function.So it worked fine.And about the msg indeded I forgot to place a '$'

Comment: @TheNiv: I updated this answer to mention the 8-bit vs. 16-bit number difference, adding explicit leading zeros for how your program treats the number as 16-bit.  This already got mentioned in answers or comments on one of your previous questions.  It's not clear what the rule is supposed to be for 8-bit vs. 16-bit rotate.  Are you supposed to use an 8-bit rotate if the number is `<= 0xFF`?

Comment: @PeterCordes Im pretty sure that I dont need to use an 8 bit rotation if the number is <=0xFF.  If I am,my teacher was not clear at all and didn't mention it. Honestly that might be what she meant,I don't see what else can it be.Posted this question because it isn't related directly to the old question.

Comment: @PeterCordes : In the original hebrew they talk about numbers, and I agree they also give an example of an 8-bit value being a `number`. Maybe everywhere they say number they mean `byte`? The example would be the 16-bit number divided into [10010110] [01010110] . I only think that way because of how the teacher seems to have defined "number" in the example. Then the 2 cases (per byte) missed would be where things wrap on a byte boundary (rather than a 16-bit word). I had hoped thee entire original question in Hebrew would help, but I only had more questions lol